How to Intercept GraphQL Response and Use the Data in Cypress Test
I'm writing a Cypress test to verify the login functionality of my application. I need to intercept a GraphQL request, extract a value from the response, and use it in subsequent steps of the test. However, I'm encountering issues with promises and Cypress commands.
Here is my current test code:
describe('Login functionality', () => {
it('should login successfully', () => {
    const email = 'admin@email.com';
    const password = 'password';

    cy.visit('/');
    cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(email).should('have.value', email);
    cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(password);
    cy.get('[data-cy="submit-btn"]').click();

    // Intercept the GraphQL login request
    cy.intercept('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/graphql', (req) => {
        if (req.body.operationName === 'LoginVerify') {
            req.alias = 'loginVerify';
            // Continue with the request as is
            req.continue((res) => {
                // Log the response for debugging
                cy.log('Response:', res);
                // Set an alias for the response to use later
                req.reply((res) => {
                    // Assuming the OTP is in the response data
                    const testOtp = res.body.data.getTestOtp;
                    // Save the OTP value for later use
                    req.otp = testOtp;
                });
            });
        }
    });

    // Wait for the login request to complete
    cy.wait('@loginVerify').then((interception) => {
        // Extract the OTP from the intercepted response
        const testOtp = interception.request.otp;

        // Use the OTP value to complete the login process
        
    cy.get('input[type="number"]').type(testOtp).should('have.value', testOtp);
        cy.get('[data-cy="submit-btn"]').click();
        cy.wait(100);
        cy.contains('Welcome Admin');
    });
  });
});

I get the error below:

Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: loginVerify. No request ever occurred.

I've tried ensuring the intercept is set up before the actions that trigger the request and increasing the timeout, but I still encounter issues. How can I properly intercept the response, extract the OTP value, and use it in my Cypress test without running into these promise issues?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

The click should be between the intercept and the wait. You said you did this, but the code says otherwise.
So first of all, use this sequence
cy.intercept('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/graphql', (req) => {
  ...
})

cy.get('[data-cy="submit-btn"]').click();

cy.wait('@loginVerify').then((interception) => {
 ...
})

If you still see Timed out retrying after 5000ms it means that http://localhost:3000/graphql is not the correct URL.
In this case, add some wildcard characters - see url (String, Glob, RegExp). Above you used String URL pattern.
The following uses Glob URL pattern:
cy.intercept('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/graphql/**', (req) =>

If still not succeeding, switch to RegExp pattern (which is easier to match correctly):
cy.intercept('POST', /graphql/, (req) =>

Please note, regex for URL does not have any string delimiters around the regex expression - the / chars are the delimiters. If you add string delimiters, it will not work as a regex.
